# The limit $ \lim_{n \to \infty} (1- \frac{1}{n^{2}} )^{n} $

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The limit

$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  (1- \frac{1}{n^{2}} )^{n} $

So how to do this problem? We cant transform into $(1+\frac1x)^x $ @Macavity Sir please help?
How to approach?

Comment: use $a^2-b^2$ factorisation.

Comment: Take logs.$\mbox{}$

Answer (score 10):

**hint**: $\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right) = \left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$

Comment: Should this then be solved as this? $$\lim_{n \to \infty}  (1- \frac{1}{n} )^{n}\lim_{n \to \infty}  (1+ \frac{1}{n} )^{n}$$

Comment: Since both limits exist, yes.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent, the limit of a product is the product of the limits (when all of them exist).

Comment: @ClementC. Actually they have to be finite as well, on top of existing.

Comment: @rubik, yes, indeed -- I meant "exist in $\mathbb{R}$" (to avoid undefined forms such as $0\cdot\infty$). Otherwise the product of the limits may not even make sense.

Comment: Hi can someone please show me how to write MathJax in comments? Its not being rendered? In what should the tex be surrounded? seems like $(dollar sign) ( code) (dollar sign) $ is not working

Comment: It is: \$a+\ln x\$ gives $a+\ln x$.

Comment: I wonder, if there is also a way by substituting $ n^2 $ to $ u  $ and then use some basic properties of the definition of  $e$ :/

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n=\left[\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^{-n^2}\right]^{-1/n}$$

Now for the inner part, $\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1m\right)^m=e$

Now check the limit of the exponent

Comment: So what'll be the answer?

Comment: @NS, $$e^{-1/\infty}=?$$

Comment: 1 ? tai to lab da?

Comment: @NS,  $e^{-1/\infty}=1/e^{1/\infty}=1/e^0=1$ Tai to bhai?

Comment: @NS, Ekta onurodh, ekhane bangla na bybohar korai somichin

Answer (score 2):

What about a proof, which does **not** even require any knowledge about the convergence of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$:

We have the sandwhich:

$$1 \geq \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n \geq 1-\frac{1}{n}$$

, where the latter inequality follows from the well known (Maybe the first inequality taught in any first calculus course) Bernoulli's inequality.

A proof using $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to e$ (and even $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to e^{-1}$) is an overkill imho, since it uses the mathematical input, that those sequences converge (which needs some effort).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** (another possibility) write $$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n = e^{n\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}$$
and use the Taylor series expansion of $\ln(1-x)$: $\ln(1-x)=-x+o(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that :

$(1-\frac{1}{n^2})^n = e^{n \ln(1-\frac{1}{n^2}) } = e^{n (-\frac{1}{n^2}+O(\frac{1}{n^4})) }$

$= e^{-\frac{1}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^3})} \to e^0 = 1$

Comment: It comes from the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1-x)$, applied with $x=\frac{1}{n^2}$: $\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2) = -x + O(x^2)$ (the $O(\cdot)$ is the ["big-O notation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)).

Answer (score 0):

so here $ -n^{2}{\to \ -\infty}$ . so the formula does not hold..$(1+\frac1n)^n $tends to e when $n{\to \infty}$  not $-\infty$..

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~hurley/math116/section4_docs/Handouts/elimit.pdf Read this.

Comment: so what 2 do with that ?it is the proof of the formula (1+1/n)^n=e when n tends to plus infinity..

Comment: Mam please see the last line of the pdf

Comment: ok Sir,then u want to say that (1+1/n)^n tends to e when n tends to minus infinity as well..

Comment: Have you seen the last line of the link I shared?  " What about the limit as x → 0−? The similar reasoning referred to above shows that lim n→−∞(1 + 1/n)^n = e also
holds. So letting x = 1/n leads to the left-hand limit also being e

Comment: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma122/elimit.pdf see here.. appreciate the proof of e.. how its coming.. then put it on $ -\infty $ to see for yourself.. Unless you aprreciate the proof you wont get.

Comment: I think here in the document they are trying to mean something else.. I have tried to find out whether for - infinity it exists or not bt  have not yet found anything.